# Autofill down by a set of 3 cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to autofill a column by groups of 3 cells. I have a formula in the first cell which I want copied to the next two cells exactly the way it is, and then increase by one cell for the next set of three, and then one more for the next set, and so on.

So I want to be able to grab the first three cells and AutoFill with them like this:

- A1=OtherTab!A1
- A2=OtherTab!A1
- A3=OtherTab!A1
- A4=OtherTab!A2
- A5=OtherTab!A2
- A6=OtherTab!A2
- A7=OtherTab!A3
- A8=OtherTab!A3
- A9=OtherTab!A3

But I'm getting this instead:

- A1=OtherTab!A1
- A2=OtherTab!A2
- A3=OtherTab!A3
- A4=OtherTab!A4

And so on. Essentially I want to use AutoFill but on groups of 3 cells at a time. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking at the OtherTab as another Worksheet

You can use this formula to see the values on that OtherTab
This is entered in A1 on the first Sheet

```
=INDIRECT("OtherTab!A"&ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0))
```